# Zendesk API: Update Multiple Tickets at once using PUT Method? How does it look like? Javascript/Google Script

Tags: javascript, api, google-apps-script, zendesk, zendesk-api

I'm currently trying to do an API call to update multiple tickets at once using ticket IDs. These ticket IDs are stored on google Sheets since I have the script running there. I would appreciate someone sharing how to use the REST method and get it working! Thank you!

**Problem: I'm not sure how to update multiple tickets using the following**

If I try with 1 ticket ID, example `PUT https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/12345` This is from https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/tickets/#update-ticket. This will only update 1 ticket, fair.

Original Code: `PUT /api/v2/tickets/{ticket_id}` I know to just replace {ticket_id} with a ticket number. If I put something like [https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/{ticket_id}](https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/%7Bticket_id%7D) it will throw me an error.

When it comes to multiple:
(Source: https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/tickets/#update-many-tickets). How do I write the code in a way I can read multiple ticket ids at once without having to repeat it 10 time if there are 10 tickets?

`PUT https://company.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many`

Zendesk's example is saying it like this:

```
{
  "tickets": [
    { "id": 1, "status": "solved" },
    { "id": 2, "status": "pending" }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When I saw your question, I thought that your goal might be able to be achieved by modifying [this sample script](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71403404/7108653). But, from your question, in your situation, I thought that when a sample modified script is shown, it might be useful for you and other users. So I posted a modified script instead of the duplicated question.

#### Prepare Spreadsheet:

This script retrieves the values from Spreadsheet. So, please set `id` and `status` to the columns "A" and "B" of the header row. And, please set the values of `id` and `status`.

#### Sample script:

Please copy and paste the following script to the script editor of Google Spreadsheet. And please set the variables.

```js
function sample() {
  var url = 'https://{subdomain}.zendesk.com/api/v2/tickets/update_many.json'; // Please set your URL.
  var user = '###'; // Please set your user name.
  var pwd = '###'; // Please set your passworkd.
  var sheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please set the sheet name.

  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName(sheetName);
  var [headers, ...rows] = sheet.getDataRange().getDisplayValues();
  var tickets = rows.map(r => {
    var temp = {};
    headers.forEach((h, j) => {
      if (r[j] != "") temp[h] = r[j];
    });
    return temp;
  });
  var options = {
    'method': 'PUT',
    'headers': { 'Authorization': "Basic " + Utilities.base64Encode(user + ':' + pwd) },
    'payload': JSON.stringify({ tickets }),
    'contentType': 'application/json',
    'muteHttpExceptions': true
  };
  var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
  console.log(response.getContentText());
}
```

- When the values are retrieved from the Spreadsheet, `JSON.stringify({ tickets })` is as follows.

  ```
    {
      "tickets": [
        {"id": "1", "status": "status1"},
        {"id": "2", "status": "status2"},
        {"id": "3", "status": "status3"},
        ,
        ,
        ,
      ]
    }
  ```

#### Note:

- I think that if your values of `user` and `pwd` are invalid, an error occurs. At that time, please confirm your values again.

#### References:

- [Batch updates of Tickets](https://developer.zendesk.com/api-reference/ticketing/tickets/tickets/#batch-updates)

  - At `PUT /api/v2/tickets/update_many`, the document says `Accepts an array of up to 100 ticket objects, or a comma-separated list of up to 100 ticket ids.`. Please be careful about this.
- Related thread.

  - [Zendesk Update Users API From Google Sheets](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71396085)
- [fetch(url, params)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/url-fetch/url-fetch-app#fetchurl,-params)